# how to get data from server (xampp) in android when app is closed or not working in foreground?

Tags: android, kotlin, xampp, background-service

Working on an android project which get data from xampp server and generates notification on specific events. But i need to fetch data in background even when app is closed by the user. I am using Kotlin for programming.

Comment: you most likely need a background service, there is a lot of documentation about them. https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service have a read of this,

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to do a REST API call from background. For this you need to have a service and you can get more details on implementation [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/starting-background-services#:%7E:text=Service%20is%20a%20component%20which,processing%2C%20indexing%20content%2C%20etc)

Remember, service doesn't mean you can do network call call directly as you still need a separate thread.

The modern approach would be to use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)